# Imagemagick php execution on Linux Dedicated Server

Tags: php, linux, imagemagick

I'm doing some ImageMagick stuff. Here is my command:

```
/usr/bin/convert /home/setsail/public_html/microsite/images
/tmp/fe0e3b88601d254befc115ca6a50365b.png -alpha set -channel alpha -background none 
-vignette 0x3 -resize 66x89 /home/setsail/public_html/microsite/images/oval_thumb
/77bda03b6358b89efbe747ae414bd75f.png
```

This code feathers and resizes the image. It works fine on localhost (I'm using xampp on localhost) both in the shell and in php code, and works fine on my dedicated server in the shell.

But, it doesn't work at all on dedicated server with php code. Here is my code:

```
$cmd = "convert ".realpath($temp1)." -alpha set -channel alpha -background none    -vignette 0x3 resize ".$width."x".$height." ".$dest_img;
exec($cmd);
```

ImageMagick is properly installed on server and active as well as I see it in phpinfo()
Any ideas why it's happening and what should i do?

Comment: `exec()` may be disabled on your server. Check your php.ini file to see and change it if necessary.

Comment: You're not getting any command output or a return code from `exec` - which you should always be doing. If it gives a return code of zero, it was successful; if it is non-zero then check the command output as to why it failed. For example, it may have insufficient permissions to access the file in `$temp1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `convert` may not be in the `$PATH` environment variable being used by the web server.  Use the full path to `convert`:

```
// Substitute the full path for /usr/bin
$cmd = "/usr/bin/convert ".realpath($temp1)." -alpha set -channel alpha -background none    -vignette 0x3 resize ".$width."x".$height." ".$dest_img;

$results = array();
$return_code = NULL;
exec($cmd, $results, $return_code);

// Check the output of the command for error:
var_dump($results);
var_dump($return_code);
```

To find `convert`'s location, from a shell on your server do

```
$ which convert
```

Comment: And check that the command returns a zero return code too `:)`.

Comment: exec() was disabled .. Thanks for helping me find out about it :)